# Help with fitting given data through an exponential function

Tags: fitting, excel

I am trying to fit some data through the *Mathematica* function `FindFit`, however I encounter the errror:

> `FindFit::fmgz`: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a minimum; it may be a maximum or a saddle point.

My code is the following:

```
data1 = {2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016};
data2 = {0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.11, 0.1, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.07};
data = Transpose@{data1, data2};
f = Normal[FindFit[data, a*Exp[-b *x], {a, b}, x]];
k = Plot[f, {x, 2009, 2016}];
g = ListPlot[data, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[data]}];
Show[g, k, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

I used excel to fit the data and I get the following function:

$$y=7\cdot10^{61}e^{-0.072x}$$

I would like to get a similar function using *Mathematica*. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The **Possible Issues** section of the documentation says *Good starting values may be necessary to get a reasonable fit*.

It seems we don't need *much* prior knowledge to get a reasonable fit, in this case:

```
FindFit[data, 10^a*Exp[-b*x], {a, {b, 0}}, x]
```

> ```
> {a -> 59.3085, b -> 0.0690153}
> ```

Comment: Why did you add ${b,0}$? Is there a way of finding the function without giving this much information in the begining? Say the below function was not given and I wanted to approximate the data with an exponential function

Comment: @user372003 `{b, 0}` gives `b` a *starting value* of zero.  I do not know a way of making `FindFit` work with less information than this.  I do not know to what you refer when you write "the below function."

Answer (score 3):

What excel does is this:

```
data1 = {2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016};
data2 = {0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.11, 0.1, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.07};
data = Transpose@{data1, Log[data2]};
FullSimplify[Exp[Fit[data, {1, x}, x]]]
```

> $6.50414\cdot 10^{61} e^{-0.0718844 x}$

Answer (score 3):

For functions that use iterative procedures (such as `FindFit` and `NonlinearModelFit`) using "good" starting values is a fact of life.  @Mr.Wizard's answer uses a better starting value for `b` and reparameterizes the function so that `10^a` replaces `a` (which is a common necessity for nonlinear models).  That the original parameters are many orders of magnitude apart doesn't help either.

For this particular functional form one can look at a linearization of the function.  Instead of fitting

$$y=a e^{-b x} + \epsilon$$

one can consider

$$ \log{y} = \log{a} - b x + \epsilon$$

Then one can use `LinearModelFit` which does not use an iterative procedure which means there is no need to guess at starting values.  (And `LinearModelFit` is less sensitive to orders of magnitude differences in parameters although it is not completely immune.)

```
data1 = {2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016};
data2 = {0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.11, 0.1, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.07};
data = Transpose@{data1, data2};
lmf = LinearModelFit[Transpose@{data1, Log[data2]}, x, x];
lmf["BestFitParameters"]
(* {142.33012887191313, -0.07188439391126572} *)

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[Exp[lmf[x]], {x, 2008, 2016}]]
```

[image: Data and linear model fit]

Note:  This is exactly @Coolwater 's answer but much more verbose.

Comment: ...and one always has the option to use the `LinearModelFit[]`-derived parameters as seeds for further polishing with `NonlinearModelFit[]`.